# Unreachable statement in Switch statement

Tags: android, methods, android-viewpager, switch-statement, return

I have this code, and first "break;" is red underlined with error "Unreachable statement". I guess it is about figure brackets that method should return int, but I have to use if and switch statements, please, I appreciate any help

```
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                char intentA = getIntent().getCharExtra("A", 'A');

                switch (intentA) {
                    case 'A':
                        mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        return LetterFragment.newInstance(intentA);
                    **break;**
                    case 'B':
                        mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                        return LetterFragment.newInstance(intentA);
                    break;
                    case 'C':
                        mPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                        return LetterFragment.newInstance(intentA);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return new LetterFragment();

        }
```

Comment: Remove the `break` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The break statements will never be run (they are unreachable), because you always return before the break statement. Remove the break statements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need break statement in switch case after the return statement. Remove all break statements.